# NotificationCenter Post request never gets received

Tags: swift, swift3

I am trying to post a message to an observable in my app but for some reason it doesn't work at all and the only thing I can attribute it to is installing `https://bugfender.com/` can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code or how to track down the root cause as there is no error messages at all

Both snippets have been moved to AppDelegate

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


     NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("TestPost"), object: nil)
     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onDidReceiveData(_:)), name: Notification.Name("TestPost"), object: nil)

    return true
  }
```

and the receiver functions is

```
    @objc func onDidReceiveData(_ notification:Notification) {
        // Do something now
        print("XXXXXX received")
    }
```

===== Updating with my actual code for custom capacitor plugin =======

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    ... code for receiving notification starts here

     NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("TestPost"), object: nil)

    ... code for receiving notification ends here


    return true
  }
```

```
import Foundation
import Capacitor

@objc(myHelpers)
public class myHelpers: CAPPlugin {

    public override func load() {
        print("PluginLoaded")

       let nc = NotificationCenter.default
            nc.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleSignal), name: Notification.Name("TestPost"), object: nil)

    }

    @objc func handleSignal()
    {
    print("XX WE RECEIVED AN EVENT AT handleSignal")
        notifyListeners(
            "myPluginEvent",
            data: [:],
            retainUntilConsumed: true
        )
    }    


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register your observer before you post the notification.

Comment: :) that did solve the problem above. I have a curve ball for you, for my exact issue the add observer is actually in a different class within public override func load()  any idea how I can get it to work ? Im a swift noob

Comment: What is the condition that should trigger the notification? You don't want to trigger it in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` do you?

Comment: I have integrated OneSignal, it actually receives or processes the notification in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions so i want to push the notification data onto another class so that I can feed it via a bridge to an Ionic/Capacitor webview

Comment: Updated there, I left out the one signal stuff because I just need to get this post request working, then I can add the one signal stuff around it. the streange this is i had this working before but now it just does not work at all and I have no idea why

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your one signal stuff. It would help if you posted that. But...I assume one signal has a callback. You should be calling `post` from that callback.

Comment: I havent added the one signal stuff yet, Ive just been trying to get this working. I had it working before, any idea what could stop it from working or any tips on how to debug it and see why the post doesnt get received ?

Comment: Lol, ok. Well that's not going to work. didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is called before load. You need to register for the notification before you post it.

Comment: Thanks man, I think you are right! I may have had this post request outside of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions when it was working :D I cant remember though. Ill mark your answer as the correct one anyway